# Get Whatsapp Number of user in Twilio autopilot

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-autopilot

I am trying to create a chatbot using Twilio Autopilot which integrated with WhatsApp. So my flow is like, if user messages on registerd number, Twilio WhatsApp senders webhook will get trigger and it will call Autopilot chatbot task. Task will process the data and it will send reply.

In all above flow I want to capture the WhatsApp number of the user who is asking the question. that number I want in autopilot, so Autopilot will send that number to Twilio function and I want to save that number in my Database using external API's call from Twilio function.

How I will get WhatsApp number inside Twilio Autopilot chatbot for user who is asking questions?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Autopilot can respond using static actions defined within the task, but it can also send a webhook request to fetch Actions JSON from your server. That [webhook request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) contains details about the user you are talking with, including the parameter `UserIdentifier` which, in a WhatsApp chat, will be the user's WhatsApp number.

If you are currently responding to tasks from Actions JSON defined in the Twilio console, you can add a webhook by using a "redirect" action at the end of a set of actions to a URL you control and then responding to that with a "listen" action to wait for the next task. Alternatively, you could just set a URL for the webhook and respond with your Actions JSON from your own app.